# Field Type of entity-query not working, correctly retrieves list of content-items but incorrectly stores them as 'Empty Slot"

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9

I have an Authors App which has x amount of authors. I have another app and have configured an [Field Input-Type entity-query](https://docs.2sxc.org/basics/data/fields/entity-query.html) in it which pulls from the Authors App. It does this correctly and I can select multiple authors. However upon save, when I go to retrieve a content item which should contain the selected authors, [I am given "empty slot" for the place of each author](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1aLt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Real entity fields are Entity relations, and they enforce validity. So they only work with entities in the same app, as that's kind of a sealed scope. This is important that Apps can ensure export/import and still work for all standard use cases.

To reference entities of another app you must use strings instead. This can be done using the string-query field which has the same functionality.

The only downside is that your code will need to then look up the entity in the other app using the id or guid (whichever you store) in Razor.